# Group by time-series with specifc formula

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

The task is to calculate the unit time.
Formula: `(oldest_timestamp - newest_timestamp) / count_of_rows_that_matches_name` 
Formula (desc): *the time difference between the last and the first entry divided by the overall number of entries*

I need to groupby data by name and time-series column with format `10/10/19 11:11` and calculate by formula the unit time.

**Test data:**

```
name; timestamp
math; 11/14/19 14:11
math; 11/14/19 14:11
math; 11/15/19 15:49
physics; 11/15/19 12:55
physics; 11/15/19 12:57
physics; 11/15/19 16:51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the timestamp column to a `datetime64[ns]` dtype. Use `np.ptp` (peak-to-peak) to get the difference between the largest and smallest timestamp, within group, and then divide by the `size` of the group.

Both `groupby` results are Series uniquely indexed by `'name'` so pandas aligns on `'name'` for the division.

```
import numpy as np

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.groupby('name')['timestamp'].agg(np.ptp)/df.groupby('name').size()

#name
#math      0 days 08:32:40
#physics   0 days 01:18:40
#dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```